# Adding SelectedIndexChanged to generated checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a generated checkboxlist that is generated by selecting options on another checkboxlist:

```
CheckBoxList typefilter = new CheckBoxList { ID = "typefilter" + CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text };
typefilter.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
SortedList<int, string> filterValueList = new SortedList<int, string>();

typefilter.DataTextField = "Value";
typefilter.DataValueField = "Key";
typefilter.DataSource = getFilterOptions(int.Parse(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value));
typefilter.DataBind();

phSelectedItem.Controls.Add(typefilter);
```

Now the problem is if I want to give my generated checkboxlist a SelectedIndexChanged, how do I go about doing it?

Edit (After using the suggested handler method, clicking the checkbox will destroy the entire checkboxlist):
Entire method's code

```
protected void cbl_RentalCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbl_RentalCategory.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        Label selectedType = new Label { ID = "Title" };
        selectedType.Text = "<h3>Rental Items</h3>";

        phSelectedItem.Controls.Add(selectedType);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cbl_RentalCategory.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cbl_RentalCategory.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            Label selectedType = new Label { ID = "selectedType" + cbl_RentalCategory.Items[i].Text };
            selectedType.Text = cbl_RentalCategory.Items[i].Text + "<br/>";

            phSelectedItem.Controls.Add(selectedType);

            CheckBoxList typefilter = new CheckBoxList { ID = "typefilter" + cbl_RentalCategory.Items[i].Text };
            typefilter.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
            SortedList<int, string> filterValueList = new SortedList<int, string>();
            typefilter.AutoPostBack = true;
            typefilter.SelectedIndexChanged += typefilter_SelectedIndexChanged;
            typefilter.DataTextField = "Value";
            typefilter.DataValueField = "Key";
            typefilter.DataSource = getFilterOptions(int.Parse(cbl_RentalCategory.Items[i].Value));
            typefilter.DataBind();

            phSelectedItem.Controls.Add(typefilter);

            Label nextLine = new Label { ID = "nextLine" + cbl_RentalCategory.Items[i].Text };
            nextLine.Text = "<br/>";
            phSelectedItem.Controls.Add(nextLine);
        }
    }
}
```

getFilterOptions():

```
private SortedList<int, string> getFilterOptions(int typeID)
{
    SortedList<int, string> filterValueList = new SortedList<int, string>();

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOMEDB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM SOMEWHERE WHERE ID=@ID", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", typeID);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            filterValueList.Add(int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString()), reader["InformationHeader"].ToString());
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    return filterValueList;
}
```

Comment: something like [`typefilter.SelectedIndexChanged += yourhandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understood your problem, you need to dynamically create checkboxlist and this dynamically generated checkboxlist should also support AutoPostBack with SelectedChange Event.

**Steps to run Sample :**

Step-1 : Create a simple website in Visual Studio

Step-2 : Place below code in default.aspx.cs file, leave using namespace as they are.

Step-3 : Place aspx code in  default.aspx file

**Expected Output :**
A checkbox list will come on default page load.
Select any item of dropdown.
Code will generate seperate checkboxlist (subitem) list for each selection.
Select any item in seperately generated checkboxlist and selected value will be shown in Label on screen.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string[] arrMasterDDLSelItem;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (masterCheckBoxList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        arrMasterDDLSelItem = new string[masterCheckBoxList.Items.Count];
        ListItem objListItem;
        for (int index = 0; index < masterCheckBoxList.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            objListItem = masterCheckBoxList.Items[index] as ListItem;
            if (objListItem.Selected)
                arrMasterDDLSelItem[index] = objListItem.Text;
        }
        if (arrMasterDDLSelItem.Count() > 0)
            RecreateControls(arrMasterDDLSelItem);
    }
}
protected void typefilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList objCheckBoxList = sender as CheckBoxList;
    ListItem objListItem;
    string selectedItems=string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in objCheckBoxList.Items)
    {
        objListItem=item as ListItem;
        if (objListItem.Selected)
            selectedItems += " " + objListItem.Text + ",";
    }
    Label1.Text = selectedItems;
}

private SortedList<int, string> getFilterOptions(string selItem)
{
    SortedList<int, string> filterValueList = new SortedList<int, string>();
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        filterValueList.Add(index, "SubItem -" + index.ToString() + " For " + selItem);
    return filterValueList;
}
private void RecreateControls(string[] masterSelectedItem)
{
    foreach (var item in masterSelectedItem)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            CheckBoxList typefilter = new CheckBoxList { ID = "typefilter" + item };
            typefilter.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
            SortedList<int, string> filterValueList = new SortedList<int, string>();
            typefilter.AutoPostBack = true;
            typefilter.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(typefilter_SelectedIndexChanged);
            typefilter.DataTextField = "Value";
            typefilter.DataValueField = "Key";
            typefilter.DataSource = getFilterOptions(item);
            typefilter.DataBind();
            ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            MainContent.Controls.Add(typefilter);
        }
    }
}
```

}

ASPX Code :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content><asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="masterCheckBoxList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Type-1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Type-2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Type-3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDropDownList" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Apologies code may have optimization scope as written in very limited period to give only idea of solution to your problem. But tested and working fine with above mentioned details.
Note Reference of this example is taken from 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Dynamic-DropDownList-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this.Set `Autopostback` to true and create `selectedindexchanged` method. Make sure you run this code only first time when page loads.

```
if(!IsPostBack){
CheckBoxList typefilter = new CheckBoxList { ID = "typefilter" + CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text };
typefilter.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
SortedList<int, string> filterValueList = new SortedList<int, string>();
typefilter.AutoPostBack = true;
typefilter.SelectedIndexChanged += typefilter_SelectedIndexChanged;
typefilter.DataTextField = "Value";
typefilter.DataValueField = "Key";     
typefilter.DataSource = getFilterOptions(int.Parse(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value));
typefilter.DataBind();

phSelectedItem.Controls.Add(typefilter);
}
```

and here is you selectedindex change method

```
public void typefilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code given and when I click any checkboxlist items, the whole checkbox list simply disappears.

Im just trying to put textbox1.Text = "Something";

Comment: Make sure your code which binds this list runs only when page is loaded first time

Comment: I tried this already, but when I put the !IsPostBack, the checkbox will not be generated
I have edited the thread with the entire code for that, maybe the problem lies with the first checkboxlist

Comment: you will be missing something because !IsPostBack has nothing to do with generation of items.

Comment: I think you are generating dynamic checkboxlist in loop and you are creating only one selectedindexchanged for every checkboxlist that may be causing the issue.

Comment: wow that sounds tough, Is it possible to create selectedindexchanged dynamically? Let me try it individually to see if it works. Edit: Tried it for just 1, doesnt work too

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you are creating CheckBoxList from code behind?

As I understand your requirement is: show a master checkbox list (RentalCategory) and for each selection of the checkbox, show a label (selectedType*) and another checkbox list (typefilter*).

For this kind of requirement I would use a repeater control that has the selectedType Label and typefilter CheckBoxList in the item template, assigning SelectedIndexChanged event handler for typefilter at design time only.

From the codebehind, I'll execute 2 select statements (one on the master table-RentalCategory, another on details table-typefilter with appropriate filter condition: where @ID in (<IDs of selected checkboxes in RentalCategory list>) ) in one go [assumtion: you don't have too much of data]

This will give me a DataSet with 2 DataTables. I'll add 1 DataRelation and use this complete DataSet to bind with master checkbox list as well as repeater (with Row.GetChildRows or CreateChildView).

For understanding the concept check:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/nestedrepeaters-csharp/